# Hyper-efficient number systems

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, number-systems

In any (standard) positional number system, the number of symbols required to represent a number $n$ is asymptotic to $O(\text{ln}(n))$. For example, in the base 2 (binary), the number of symbols required to represent $n$ is $\text{floor}(\text{log}_2(n))+1$.

In constrast, in most tally mark systems, the number of symbols required to represent a number $n$ is asymptotic to  $O(n)$. These systems are less efficient than the positional number systems since numbers require exponentially more symbols to represent.

## My question

I want to know if there exist systems that are even more efficient than the positional number systems, perhaps on the cor even $O(1)$ level, which only have a finite number of symbols.

The only one I could find online is called [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), but it requires an infinite number of symbols.

**UPDATE**: I also am open to non-positional systems, as long as they are below $O(\text{ln}(n))$ and use a finite collection of symbols.

Comment: Pigeonhole principle

Comment: you can cheat by using position. For example consider our system but in each position you can put the digit on top, or in the middle or in the bottom, then instead we would get $30$ options for our "10" symbols. You can also get an extra digit by allowing places to be empty and such.

Comment: @Onir That doesn't change $O(\ln n)$...

Comment: And to OP, no, it is not possible, without an infinite collection of symbols, in which case you can do it with $O(1)$.

Comment: @DonThousand is it impossible even for O(ln(ln(n)))?

Comment: @Nirvana yes. $k$ symbols mean the best you can do is $O(\log_k n)$

Comment: You can always draw a line that is $\frac{1}{n}$ cm long to represent $n$. Well, you cant actually do it now I think about it.

Comment: One argument that can be made is that if you have an image with $x$ pixels where every pixel can take at most $c$ distinguishable colors then there is at most $c^x$ different images.

Comment: I think it is possible to add enough restrictions that a reasonable number system must satisfy to prove no hyper-efficient number system exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $c$ symbols and use $n$ of them there are only $c^n$ different strings, so that is the most numbers you can represent.  That means to represent all the numbers up to $N$ you need $\log_c(N)$ symbols.